# src package disappear

Tags: android, eclipse

I drag my package from eclipse src folder on Windows mail window to send it by mail, but package after drag the package became white and all the java inside disappears!! What happens! I can't found them anywhere. I try to restart eclipse.

Comment: turns white where?  why not just copy the package?

Comment: white, the color of the icon of the package in eclipse. Dragging the single java file in windowsmail to send it always works but dragging the package I lost all.